# How to change the mention plugin output DOM element in ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5, mention

Actual Output

```
<span class="mention" data-mention="@lilypad">@lilypad</span>
```

Tried below,

```
writer.createUIElement( 'span', null, function( domDocument ) {
 const domElement = this.toDomElement( domDocument );
 domElement.innerHTML = 'this is ui element';
 return domElement;
} );
```

Like mentioned here
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_writer-Writer.html

```
editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).attributeToElement( { model: 'mention', view: ( modelAttributeValue, { writer } ) => { 
writer.createUIElement( 'span', null, function( domDocument ) {
 const domElement = this.toDomElement( domDocument );
 domElement.innerHTML = 'this is ui element';
 return domElement;
});
}
});
```

But its not working

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFIPS.png)

Expected output

```
<span class="mention mention-parent" data-mention="@lilypad" id="parent-id">@lilypad<span class="mention mention-child" id="child-id">Sample text</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation for this!

[Fully customized mention feed](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html#fully-customized-mention-feed)

Here they mention to use the property `itemRenderer: customItemRenderer` in the object of `feeds` array. We can modify the function to suit your needs!

```
function customItemRenderer( item ) {
    const itemElement = document.createElement( 'span' );

    itemElement.classList.add( 'mention-parent' );
    itemElement.id = `mention-list-item-id-${ item.userId }`;
    itemElement.textContent = `${ item.name } `;

    const usernameElement = document.createElement( 'span' );

    usernameElement.classList.add( 'mention-parent' );
    usernameElement.textContent = item.id;

    itemElement.appendChild( usernameElement );

    return itemElement;
}
```

This demo does not get the desired output, but its a good starting point to solve your issue!

Comment: Thanks Naren Murali for your effort,

This can be useful for only mention dropdown design change, its not changing the dom after selection

Comment: @JeyanBright please update the details on the question itself, not editing this answer, thanks!